# Delphi (2006): how to Split by new line and break at the same time

Tags: delphi, split, newline, line-breaks, delphi-2006

I have this simple operation in Java, where the string is split by new line and break.

```
String i= "Holidays 
    
           Great. 
           Bye";
String []linesArray = i.split("\\r?\\n");
```

I would like to obtain the same result in Delphi 2006.

Is it valid to use the following steps?

```
charArray[0] := '\\r';
charArray[1] := '\\n';

strArray     := strA.Split(charArray);
```

Comment: You should specify your Delphi version. Also, you might want to clarify the question. I interpret the Q like this: "Split a string at both CR and LF." which implies that CRLF gives an empty string element. For instance, 'alpha'#13'beta'#10'gamma'#13#10'delta' yields 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', '', and 'delta'. Recall that many Delphi experts don't know Java.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Delphi 10

Comment: Thanks, then it is really easy.

Comment: Delphi 10 was released in 2015.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: by wiki 
In late 2005 Delphi 2006 (Delphi 10, also Borland Developer Studio 4.0)

Comment: I think most people think of Delphi 10 Seattle released in 2015 when you say "Delphi 10". The current version of Delphi is 10.4.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand your solution can work as well for a version of delphi 2006

Comment: I don't think `TStringHelper` is present in Delphi 2006.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Can work your code for an old version of Delphi?

Comment: I'll add a version for old Delphi.

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError Why are you using such an old Delphi version? Converting Java to Delphi will be much more easier using latest Delphi version. Delphi has really been enhanced during all those days. You can try the latest version (30 days trial) or use the Community Edition (Free of charge for personal use or very small business). Community Edition is not the latest version (10.3 vs 10.4.2). Delphi 10.4.2 is actually version number 27!

Comment: The Java code does not split at delphi #13#10 - it splits at #10 and ignores #13 if it is at the end of the string.  A RegEx will do exactly this for you, I don't know if that's in the version of Delphi you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret your request like this: "Split a string at both CR and LF." which implies that CR+LF gives an empty string element. For instance, `'alpha'#13'beta'#10'gamma'#13#10'delta'` yields the five elements `'alpha'`, `'beta'`, `'gamma'`, `''`, and `'delta'`.

If so, and if you are using a non-ancient version of Delphi, this is really simple:

```
var S := 'alpha'#13'beta'#10'gamma'#13#10'delta';

var Parts := S.Split([#13, #10]);
for var Part in Parts do
  ShowMessage(Part);
```

## For old Delphi versions

The code above requires `TStringHelper` (crucially) and also makes use of inline variable declarations, `for in` loops, and generics.

For old Delphi versions, you can do it manually:

```pascal
type
  TStringArray = array of string;

function Split(const S: string): TStringArray;
var
  Count: Integer;
const
  Delta = 512;

  procedure Add(const Part: string);
  begin
    if Length(Result) = Count then
      SetLength(Result, Length(Result) + Delta);
    Result[Count] := Part;
    Inc(Count);
  end;

var
  p, i: Integer;

begin

  Result := nil;
  Count := 0;

  p := 0; // previous delim
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    if S[i] in [#13, #10] then
    begin
      Add(Copy(S, Succ(p), i - p - 1));
      p := i;
    end;

  Add(Copy(S, Succ(p)));

  SetLength(Result, Count);

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  Parts: TStringArray;
  i: Integer;
begin

  S := 'alpha'#13'beta'#10'gamma'#13#10'delta';

  Parts := Split(S);
  for i := 0 to High(Parts) do
    ShowMessage(Parts[i]);

end;
```

Comment: Should I copy all this code for a simple split?

Comment: Really useful answer, but the problem is to split at #10 and ignore #13 if it's at the end of a string ...

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError: You would put the `Split` function in your utilities unit. Then every time you need to split a string at #13 and #10 separately, you just need to write `Split(mystring)` to get the parts as an array of strings.

Comment: @RobLambden: That wasn't at all obvious from the Q (I don't know Java!).

Comment: I realise it's not obvious - which is why I pointed it out - but your answer is good and very well presented!

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError: As fpiette said above, modern Delphi versions are *much*, much easier to work with.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I know but this doesn't depend by me. Thank you very much for your help.